I keep getting the same error when making an onclick function passing through jinja variables
I keep getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at bestellen:60:105)
this is my html:
  <div class="gerechten">
    {% for gerecht in gerechten %}
    
    <div class="Gerechtdiv">
      <img src={{gerecht.url}} class="gerechtimg">
      <h3 class="GerechtTitel">{{gerecht.gerecht}}</h3>
      <p class ="GerechtBeschrijving">{{gerecht.beschrijving}}</p>
      <div class ="BottomGerechtDiv">
        <p style="font-size: 17px;"><b>€{{gerecht.prijs}}</b></p>
        <p>{{gerecht.sterren}}&#9733</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button" onclick="addItemToCart({{gerecht.gerecht}}, {{gerecht.prijs}})" style="cursor: pointer"><span>Voeg toe aan winkelwagen</span> </button>
    </div>
    
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

the line the error is referring to is the button line.
i tried clearing the onclick function, then it works, but when i put in the function it gives me an error again

Just curious... Is there a reason for the double braces around gerecht.gerecht, but only single braces around gerecht.prijs?

That was a typo, but it is not what causes the error unfortunatly

The error says its line 60. What line is 60 in your provided code?

its this line: Voeg toe aan winkelwagen 

What is gerecht.gerecht? If this holds multiple words like Some super cool product, you'll have to quote it in JS: addItemToCart('{{gerecht.gerecht}}', {{gerecht.prijs}}). Same goes for gerecht.prijs.

the first gerecht is the name of the variable in the database and the second gerecht is the title of the variable in the database

but what is the VALUE returned by those - the value must be in quotes perhaps

the value that is returned by gerecht.gerecht is a string and gerecht.prijs is an integer

It could be that {gerecht.prijs} is missing one pair of {}. So you should write:
<button class="button" onclick="addItemToCart({{gerecht.gerecht}}, {{gerecht.prijs}})" style="cursor: pointer"><span>Voeg toe aan winkelwagen</span> </button>


I tried it but i still got the same error

The error you get is a Javascript error.
addItemToCart({{gerecht.gerecht}}, {{gerecht.prijs}})

is being evaluated and you will need to find out what the values of gerecht.gerecht and gerecht.prijs is. If your code ends up looking like
addItemToCart(5, "a" b);

which reproduces your problem:


function addItemToCart() {} //mocking the function
addItemToCart(5, "a" b);
console.log(1);



then the problem is explained. So it all boils down to your template values.

gerecht.gerecht is just a string and gerecht.prijs is an integer, so i dont know if it is what you are saying

@lukasTori what are their values when you test? Can you tell me their values?
